# Flutter windows app wanting to detect the NFC reader connected via USB

Tags: flutter, dart, winapi, usb, usbserial

Hello everyone I am new to the community (Flutter community) and I want to build an app where basically my Windows app will interact with an NFC tag reader/writer that will get connected to my laptop via USB. So when the NFC reads a tag, the code must get transmitted to my app and vice-versa if I want to write something to a tag I have to be able to do it using the windows app and send the code to the NFC reader writer that will write that data to the tag.

My question is: does anyone implemented something like this or a plug-in or something that allows me to connect the NFC reader to the windows app?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this with the links below? Any advice for people who want to do the same?

Comment: I mean I managed to connect the USB and see it using a flutter web app, not a windows app but you still can not send and receive data.

Answer (score 0):

NFC related development SDK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/_nfpdrivers/

Here is a project about NFC Class Extension that you can check out.

https://github.com/microsoft/NFC-Class-Extension-Driver